# Sorting Array of Pointers to Pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have a struct holding an int.

```
typedef struct n {
    int cars;
    struct n *next;
} node;
```

I make nodes such as `node *temp;`
This is because I start with a linked list, and then go through it and add them to an array.

Which are then added to an array `node **arr;`

So I have an array of pointers to pointers. My question is: how can I do a qsort on this? My attempts up to now have resulted in:

```
qsort(arr, numberCars, sizeof(node), sortCars);

int sortCars(const void *i1, const void *i2){
    node *a = (node*)i1, *b = (node*)i2;
    return (a->cars - b->cars);
}
```

I'm having difficulty figuring out what qsort is actually pointing to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have an array of **pointers**, your function should compare between pointers:

```
int sortCars(const void *i1, const void *i2){
    node *a = *(node**)i1, *b = *(node**)i2;
    return (a->cars - b->cars);
}
```

Also, you should pass `sizeof(node*)` instead of `sizeof(node)`.

BTW, `qsort` sort the elements in the array, but not effects `next`, so your linked list will remain unsorted.

Answer (score 0):

If the nodes have `next` pointers, that suggests a linked list. That's not the same as an array. Are you sure you're allocating all the structs in a contiguous memory block? That's what a sort algorithm will need as the first argument.

```
typedef struct n {
    int cars;
} node;

node arr[10]; // ten nodes as an array
```

(How would a general sorting function know to update the `next` pointers in a struct that you defined?)

Also if `arr` is `node **arr`, that's not an array of pointers to pointers. It's a pointer to a pointer, or (roughly equivalent) an array of arrays, a pointer to an array or an array of pointers.

Comment: I have them set up as a linked list, and then made an array from that.

Answer (score 0):

The comparator function must return int:

```
int sortCars(const void *i1, const void *i2)
```

An also you may do this function more simple:

```
int sortCars(const void *i1, const void *i2){
    return ((*((node**) i1))->cars - (*((node**) i2))->cars);
}
```